# ¿como cambio el background-color del navbar en reactstrap?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, npm, reactstrap

Estoy usando [reacstrap](https://reactstrap.github.io/) en un proyecto de react.js y me gustaria saber como cambio el background color, [en la documentacion del componente](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/navbar/) dice que se puede le puede pasar propiedades, pero no se como hacerlo porque ya he intentado con: `<Navbar color="MI COLOR PERSONALIZADO (EJEMPLO #FFFFF)" light expand="md">` y no funciona.

El codigo del componente es el mismo que esta en [en la documentacion](https://reactstrap.github.io/components/navbar/) ya que lo unico que he hecho ha sido copiar y pegar.

Comment: Yo queria pasar un color como prop pero como hasta ahora no eh conseido como, esta es la repuesta que mas me ha dejado sastifecho https://stackoverrun.com/es/q/11927480

Answer (score 0):

Las propiedades de color que acepta el componente, tal como en bootstrap, son `dark` o `light`.

Para cambiar el `background-color` de la navbar lo podés hacer por css, llamando a su clase y con un !important

Comment: no quiero hacerlo con el !important porque es mala practica ¿hay otra forma?

Comment: Le podés sacar la prop del color y ponerle un class, custom-nav o el que quieras y en el css llamar a esa clase y ponerle el background-color que necesites